# add extra parameter to ProgressChanged event in C#4

Tags: c#, webclient

Here is my code (Simple Downloader):

```
public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress, string location)
    {
        using (webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            Uri URL = urlAddress.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? new Uri(urlAddress) : new Uri("http://" + urlAddress);
            try
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

& Here is my question:

How to add extra parameter (`int RowNumber`) to my `ProgressChanged` event? I mean like this:

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, int RowNumber)
    {
           // Other codes here
    }
```

& Here is the error that VS2010 gives me:

> No overload for 'ProgressChanged' matches delegate
>   'System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler'

should I override `DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler`?! how?!

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: That's not possible.  Capture it with a lambda expression.

Comment: I tried & I guess it not answered! (ProgressChanged) event runs multiple time, I want to send a number into it so stays the same after I sent another number. but this way it changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this:

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
```

with:

```
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, RowNumber));
```

Comment: it gives me ("RowNumber" does not exist) error my friend. can it be solved?

Comment: u should keep private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, int RowNumber) without changes
or try to add:
int RowNumber = 0;
between those functions

Comment: I didn't changed anything except the line you wrote. it gives me error.

Comment: You don't even need `new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler`; just do `webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, RowNumber);`

Comment: try adding int RowNumber = 0; before DownloadFile function

Comment: Thanks @YuraBelov & @Jacob worked like charm. I had to add an `int` value to `DownloadFile` inputs and give that to `RowNumber`