# How to show individual ProgressBar for Parallel Download?

Tags: .net

I am using a WebClient and downloading 4 files simultaneously. The files are downloaded in parallel and i can see the file size changing in the folder. Now i want to show progress bar for each individual files. Here is what i tried so far, but the progress is not happening. Can someone please help

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
            List<String> files = new List<String>();
            String localPath = "";
            files.Add(file1);
            files.Add(file2);
            files.Add(file3);
            files.Add(file4);

            foreach (String fi in files)
            {
                localPath = "C:\\Download\\" + fi.Split('/')[5].ToString();
                WebClient client = new WebClient();

                client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender1, e1) => client_DownloadProgressChanged(sender1, e1, z);

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fi), localPath, count);
                count += 1;
            }
     }

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, int RowNumber)
        {
            ProgressBar[] pb = new ProgressBar[4];

            pb[RowNumber-1] = new ProgressBar();
            pb[RowNumber-1].Width = 400;
            pb[RowNumber-1].Height =20;
            pnl.Children.Add(pb[RowNumber-1]);
            pb[RowNumber-1].Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options here. The best solution would be

1. Use additional parameter in `DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler` methods for each filename.
   Look how you can do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750150/add-extra-parameter-to-progresschanged-event-in-c4)
2. Use different `DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler`
3. Many other options i.e. `Parallel.ForEach`

1st solution code (not tested - I don't have the access to the IDE now)

```
List<String> files = new List<String>();
List<ProgressBar> pbs = new List<ProgressBar>();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10; 
    String localPath = "";
    files.Add(file1);
    files.Add(file2);
    files.Add(file3);
    files.Add(file4);   

    foreach (String fi in files)
    {
        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
        pb.Width = 400;
        pb.Height =20;
        pnl.Children.Add(pb);
        pbs.add(pb);

        localPath = "C:\\Download\\" + fi.Split('/')[5].ToString();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender1, e1) => client_DownloadProgressChanged(sender1, e1, fi);

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fi), localPath, count);
        count += 1;
    }
}


void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, string fi)
{       
    int pbNumber = files.IndexOf(fi);           
    pbs[pbNumber].Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Ok I replaced the line to pass addtional parameter, however it is giving error 
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) => client_DownloadProgressChanged(sender, e, z);
A local variable sender cannot be declared in this scope

Comment: "A local variable sender cannot be declared in this scope" is because you have 1st method `Button_Click` parameter named sender. Just change the name of any duplicated variable names

Comment: ouch.. i did and now it shows the progress but not updating

Comment: Did you really just do that? Did you understand anything from the link I provided? Do you have any rows in your method? What were you trying to achieve? I am gonna change the code for you but just so you know you won't learn anything that way.

Comment: i have your code but now its not even downloading.. 0KB files and it doesn't hit DownloadProgressChanged method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112288/discussion-between-ssk-and-peuczynski).